# How can I make this code (that is usually in a loop) faster and efficiently?

Tags: c#, performance

When I have a place with limited space, where I entry a text that can be few letters or huge amount of text because it's dynamic, I'm using this code to make the text fit the specific space.

```
#region TextSizing
string textSizing = databaseTable.Description;
using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    size = g.MeasureString(textSizing, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14)).Width;
}

if (size < 1500)
    lblText.Text = textSizing;
else
    lblText.Text = textSizing.Length > 135 ? textSizing.Remove(135) + "..." : textSizing;
#endregion
```

A friend of mine suggested that I should use cache to store the Font and the Graphics, I didn't understand it very well, but keep thinking about it... **How can I make this code (that is usually in a loop) faster and efficiently ?**

Comment: Not sure how to put a good title for this question, so **please** feel free to change it so it can be fit more the Q&A format. thanks.

Comment: You should use the unicode character ellipsis `…`, and not three dots. You might also be interested in https://gist.github.com/4250125

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cache the instance of `Graphics` and `Font` objects so that you don't need to create them  each time you measure the length of string. I've created a small test to see which part takes most of the time:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    stopwatch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            var size = g.MeasureString("asdasdf", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14)).Width;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Current solution - create a new Graphics per measure: {0} milliseconds", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    stopwatch.Restart();
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            var size = g.MeasureString("asdasdf", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14)).Width;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Measure the string with Graphics cached: {0} milliseconds", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    stopwatch.Restart();
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
    using (var font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            var size = g.MeasureString("asdasdf", font).Width;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Measure the string with Graphics and font cached: {0} milliseconds", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Results on my computer are:

```
Current solution - create a new Graphics per measure: 26864 milliseconds
Measure the string with Graphics cached: 6588 milliseconds
Measure the string with Graphics and font cached: 803 milliseconds
```

So by caching `Graphics` you'll reduce the time consumption by 75%, and by caching both `Font` and `Graphics` you get a nice 33.5X performance boost :).

Comment: Thank you very much for your hard work. This help me more than I expected =)

Comment: Now I just need to figure out a way to do this as a method.

Comment: @MichelAyres see updated answer for better results :)